# How can I prevent mongosh from saving db.auth password to the repl history?

Tags: mongodb, security, macos-sonoma

If I run `db.auth("myusername", "mypassword")` in an instance of `mongosh`, and then I open `.mongodb/mongosh/mongosh_repl_history` from my home directory in my editor, I see the password has clearly been saved to this file in cleartext. How do I prevent this from occurring?

I'm using MongoDB Community Edition 7.0 on MacOS Sonoma 14.3.1

Comment: Did you try with `--norc` option when starting mongosh? this option tells mongosh not to load the user configuration file, so IMO includes the command history.

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub I did try with `--norc` but then I exited the mongosh, and ran `cat ~/.mongodb/mongosh/mongosh_repl_history` and was able to see the password in cleartext still.

Comment: I filed a bug in JIRA here https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOSH-1729

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Configure mongosh](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/reference/configure-shell-settings/#std-label-mongosh-shell-settings) parameter `redactHistory`

However, the default is `remove`, thus by default it should not store the credentials as clear text by default.

If this would be the case, then I strongly suggest to create an urgent ticket at https://jira.mongodb.org/

Comment: To be clear, I cannot navigate through history in mongosh and see my password, but the password is stored in cleartext in the repl history file.